# How to make it two seconds for Time.time?

Tags: colors, unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
var targetscript : Diamond;
var red : Color;
var orange : Color;

function Start () {
    gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = red;
}

function Update () {
    if (targetscript.score > 4) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(red, orange, Time.time);
    }
}
```

So right now, if the score is larger than 4 then it would change the camera background color to orange with lerp. But its too quick. I read on the internet that Time.time is 1 second. What is the alternative way but for 2 or 3 seconds? I tried this : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/328891/controlling-duration-of-colorlerp-in-seconds.html I tried the code for the voted answer but it didn't work. It still lerps through quickly. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Time.time gives you the time in seconds since the start of the game. What you want is Time.deltaTime which is the time difference between each frames.

```
var targetscript : Diamond;
var red : Color;
var orange : Color;
var t : float = 0;
var duration : float = 3.0; //however long you want it to be

function Start () {
    gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = red;
}

function Update () {
    if (targetscript.score > 4) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(red, orange, t);
        t += Time.deltaTime/duration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Color.Lerp(Color a, Color b, float t), so:
-> t = 0, the Color result is a
-> t = 0.5, the Color result is half a and half b
-> t = 1.0, the Color result is b

Based on that definition, when Time.time return value >= 1.0 the Lerp will be completed. That's why your code finish in 1 seconds.
so, you can change the update function like this:

```
var duration : float = 3.0; //however long you want it to be
function Update ()
{
    if (targetscript.score > 4)
    {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(red, orange, Time.time / duration);
    }
}
```

This will make the Lerp completes exactly as the duration. because **Time.time / duration >= 1 when Time.time >= duration**.